# hotspot auto opens spash page except when i enable my firewall

Tags: networking

when connecting to my Pi hotspot, everything works great. however, i'd like to lock it down. i found and use the following configuration. when i do this, the configuration seems to work perfectly. however, when connecting to the network my splash page no longer opens up automatically.

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [23:2584]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1161:105847]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

any help getting my Pi firewall running and allowing the spash page to continue to start upon connection would be most appreciated. thanks.

Comment: `configuration seems to work perfectly` ... if that is true, then why are you posing a question?

Comment: yes, the configuration works.. however, when i connect to the network, my connecting device no longer opens up the splash page automatically. if the firewall is off, the splash page opens up perfectly upon connecting to my hotspot. when the firewall is on, the splash page no longer opens automatically. i want to be able to have the firewall on and the splash page work at the same time.